# Exsheets doesn't work

Tags: texmaker, exsheets

When I try to run a document using the exsheets-package, i get an error message on one of my computers.
I use Texmaker 5.0.4.

This is the document

```
\documentclass[12pt, norsk, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

This is my error message:

```
! LaTeX error: "xparse/unknown-argument-type"
!
! Unknown argument type 'b' for the command '\environment tasks'.
!
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?
It works on my other computer, I think I fixed it, but don't remember how.

Comment: If it works on one computer but not another, try updating the packages.

Comment: The b argument type is currently legal, but there is no history of when it was added.  Possibly  at some point the entire package was rewritten using expl3 (Klingon LaTeX).

Comment: The argument type `b` was added in [`xparse` 2019/03/05](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/l3packages/CHANGELOG.md#2019-03-05). So you might use an old version of `xprase`. Also `xparse` is part of package bundle `l3package`, so you need to run `tlmgr upgrade l3packages` to upgrade `xparse`, if you are using texlive and the texlive is not too old to not upgradable.

Comment: Your version of `exsheets` is newer than at least one package it depends on. As a rule of thumb you should newer update single packages, always the distribution…